# How to enable translation for file entities?

Tags: entities

I need to import files (images) that have a title and description, for multiple languages.

When I go at *admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/edit/fields/file.image.field_image_title_text* to enable translation for this field, it says ***To configure translation for this field, enable language support for this type.***

When I go at *admin/config/regional/content-language?destination=/en/admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/edit/fields/file.image.field_image_title_text* and check File in **Custom language settings**, I see following message : **File (Translation is not supported).**

How do I enable field translation for file entities?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you want to translate file entities? Because title and descriptions are usually stored in the field. If you want a translatable entity for these kind of data then use the media entity.

Comment: Well I need an additional description field for images (plus title and alt texts).
I'm trying to find my way with media_entity

Comment: file_entity is basically deprecated, media entity is the way forward and supports translations.

Comment: Ok, thank you b oth for your answers, I managed to import all my files with multilingual titles and descriptions using media_entity! :)